# How to match the id's to names iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

1. I am getting Names and ID's from DB... and storing those values in Array... Like Names storing in NamesArray and ID's storing in IDsArray...

Example:
NamesArray - {Peter, Arnold, John,Samuel}

IDsArray  - {1, 2, 3,4}

After getting those values from DB... I am sorting NamesArray... It will come like this...

NamesArray Value - {Arnold,John,Peter,Samuel}

How to change the IDsArray according to the NamesArray?

1. The same scenario is needed  for Search functionality....

Example:
I am searching 'P' text in SearchBar... It will show 'Peter' in TableView...

How to get the IDs from idarray according to the Searched Text?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't you store an custom object, having both the name and the Id in one array?

Answer (score 1):

You could use an array of dictionaries with keys Name and ID. After you could use NSPredicate for your search and NSSortDescriptor for sorting

```
yourArray: (
    {
        id = 1;
        name = Peter;
    },
    {
        id = 2;
        name = Arnold;
    },
    {
        id = 3;
        name = John;
    },
    {
        id = 4;
        name = Samuel;
    });
```

Sort

```
nameDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
nameDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:nameDescriptor];
sortedArray = [yourArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:nameDescriptors];
```

Filter

```
NSString *strToFilter = @"P";

NSArray *filteredNames = [yourArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(name BEGINSWITH[c] %@)", strToFilter]];
```

Answer (score 1):

For this scenario simple logic can be done.

NamesArray - {Peter, Arnold, John,Samuel}
IDsArray - {1, 2, 3,4}

Have the searched names in separate array which will not affect NamesArray when you search.

searchedNamesArray - {Peter}

after that get the index of the searched object from array

```
for (NSString *value in searchedNamesArray)
{

NSInteger index = [NamesArray indexOfObject:value];

// you will get the index of the object from which you can use from getting the id from IDsArray

NSLog(@"ID - %@", [IDsArray objectAtIndex:index]);
}
```

Comment: how to get the id if an array contains same name twice or thrice(while searching....?

Comment: instead of NSLog, add that `[IDsArray objectAtIndex:index]` to new array. from which you can get the id's in array.